# Deploy reports to JBoss

Tags: eclipse, jboss, birt

I want to deploy reports that are created with Birt, in Eclipse to JBoss.

Is it oki to : create a report project, after that to export it as a war and deploy it to the JBoss server?

how do i export it as a war ?

do i need to export it as a war , or I can just export it as a jar?

about the deploy :  I just have to copy the war in the deploy folder in JBoss or?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A *Thing* you deploy to JBoss is *BIRT Viewer*. BIRT Viewer is a web application that opens your reports, renders them and returns via http. There is no need to export a birt project as anything.

Here is quick "[Deploying to JBoss](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerSetup.php#jboss)" instruction for BIRT Viewer (and [Download](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/) link -  download Runtime version).

After deploy copy your `.rptdesign` files to `deploy/birt.war` dir (yeap, birt.war should be a directory). You can run your `...JBoss.../deploy/birt.war/foo.rptdesign` report as something like `http://localhost:8080/birt/frameset?__report=foo.rptdesign`.

-> More about [BIRT Viewer usage](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerUsageMain.php).

Comment: Oki, I done that, and it works.
But ...what should I do, when I need more then the report itself. More exactly...how do I export("make available") the resources that the report needs (images files, css) ?


The problem is that in the end , the output of my application should be a ".war " and it should contain amoung other stuff: reports. So how can i package a more complex project ? 

Thanks again. And sorry if i have not expresed so good and clear my issue .

Comment: The simplest is to put .rptdesign, .css, .png etc. to the same directory. There are other ways, e.g. embedding resourced in report design files. At the end you can pack entire Viewer with reports inside as .war file.

Comment: So ...this is what I have done

I have taken a example.war , expanded it, added the birt.war folder and the make it again a .war file.
After that I copied the example.war in the deploy folder of jboss.
If I acces the war, it works
http://localhost:1234/example/birt.war/
But if a try to acess a report inside the birt.war
http://localhost:1234/example/birt.war/frameset?__report=copie.rptdesign
i get HTTP Status 404 - /my/birt.war/frameset

Comment: If I acces the report just from the birt.war then it works just fine.
http://localhost:1234/birt/frameset?__report=copie.rptdesign

so

any idea what I have to change so I can acess report when birt.war is inside example.war?

and another thing
I could not create my war from scrap (well, I try to do that, but a got an error from jboss, when I used my hand made .war (The error was unable to process deployment descriptor for context /example )),
so I taken an example and used it, but I am interested to make my own .war , but do not know where to start to build it correctly ?

thank you

Comment: I see a set of possible questions here: 1. How to create own .war application  (lot of information over internet - or patient stackoverflowers will answer :) ) 2. How to use BIRT Viewer to generate report for your own web application (quite easy - internal http request to installed BIRT Viever)  3. How to generate report from inside your web application  (quite difficult - some java code using BIRT API).  4. How to create a .war containing only BIRT Viewer and your report designs  (quite easy - unjar, put files, jar, rename .jar to .war). Almost each one deserves to be a full SO question :) .